# In Java, is there any no-man's-land between overloaded and overridden methods?

Tags: java, polymorphism

In Java, is there any no-man's-land between overloaded and overridden methods? I am trying to find space between "overloaded" and "overridden".

In one scenario, I have placed two methods in a class in order to make them overloaded:

```
float my_method(int x, int y) {....}
int my_method(int x) {....}
```

Then, in another, I have modified the methods and placed them in two different classes with a hierarchical relation, in order to make them overridden:

```
void my_method(int x, int y, int z) {....}
void my_method(int x, int y, int z) {....}
```

What can be done so that the methods written above fall neither in the overloaded nor the overridden category? Is it possible? Or, are the above statements true?

```
1. Two methods that fail to be overloaded are automatically overridden
2. Two methods athat fail to be overridden are automatically overloaded
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a third scenario, in which a method of the sub-class has the same signature as a method of the super-class, but the method of the super-class is not accessible to the sub-class (i.e. it's either private or package-private and the super-class is in a different package).

In this case the method of the sub-class is not overriding the method of the super-class. It just hides it.

In super-class :

```
private void my_method(int x, int y, int z) {....}
```

In sub-class :

```
// adding @Override here would cause a compilation error
public void my_method(int x, int y, int z) {....}
```

Comment: How can it "hide" something that isn't visible in the first place?

Comment: That is what he meant by "hide".

Comment: Got some useful lines in 8.4.9 of Java SE 7 Specifications:

If two methods of a class (whether both declared in the same class, or both inherited by a class, or one declared and one inherited) have the same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the method name is said to be overloaded.

This fact causes no difficulty and never of itself results in a compile-time error. There is no required relationship between the return types or between the throws clauses of two methods with the same name, unless their signatures are override-equivalent.